# Getting error when uploading binary file of corona app using application loader

Tags: ios, coronasdk, application-loader

I am facing an issue while uploading on iTunes using application loader. Application is build using corona sdk. Error screenshot attached below.

[image]

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Review your certificates (inside developer.apple.com - certificates) and locate a certificate.

If you do not need that certificate, just click on the certificate and revoke it

You will need distribution certificate for uploading build to app store

Comment: but i already have certificate and provisioning profile on my mac